# Can I pack 2 digits(32bit) in the 12 strings [0-9a-z]{13}

Tags: algorithm

I wanna pack 2 32bit digit in to 12strings
example 
 123 456 -> abcdef0000000

Comment: You cannot pack three arbitrary 32 bit numbers in 12 base 36 digits because `(2^32)^3 > 36^12`.

Comment: Oh no How about [0-9a-zA-Z]{12}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The choice [0-9a-z] gives 36 symbols. With 12 such symbols, you get 36^12 = 4.7e18 different strings.

3 32-bit digits is the same as one 96-bit digit, which has 2^96 = 7.9e28 different values.

There are more digits than you can represent with that alphabet in 12 positions, so no, you cannot achieve the packing you want.

If you use [0-9a-zA-Z] you have 62 symbols. 62^12 = 3.2e21 - still short.

Given a number of symbols S and string length L, you can figure out how many bits of info you can store by solving S^L >= 2^B. For your case, B = 96. Let's use the Base64 alphabet, so S = 64 (this also makes the math easier). Then:

```
 64^L >= 2^96
 take log2 of both sides
 L * log2(64) >= 96 * log2(2)
 L * 6 >= 96
 L >= 16
```

So with a Base64 alphabet, you can store 96 bits in 16 symbols.

Comment: @freddiefujiwara - 2 32 bit digits is 64 bits, 2^64 = 1.8e19. Still more than 36^12 (4.7e18), but less than 62^12.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean 3 numbers:

Whether you can get them in the string depends on the language.  You can't have *ANY* limitations on the character set, though.  A 32 bit number is 4 bytes, three of them make 12 bytes.  Zeros are a possibility--any language that won't let you store a zero byte in the string won't allow this.  However, there are languages that don't care--Delphi comes to mind.  It stores strings with length codes rather than terminators and thus you can put anything in a string.

Assuming you mean 2 numbers:

[0-9][A-Z] is 36 symbols.  36^6 < 2^32, it won't work.

[0-9][A-Z][a-z] is 62 symbols.  62^6 > 2^32, you can do it.

On the other hand, if you're talking strings that hold wide characters of some type even the three numbers can easily be packed in, although you'll have to use some non-ASCII characters to do the job.  Pick any 256 symbols and you're good to go.  You can even pick 2048 symbols (you'll find more than that if you look at the east Asian languages) and pack each number into three characters.

Answer (score 0):

You are practically wanting to compact a 3 4-byte length numbers into one 12-byte length string. Yes, you can do this, but you will have to use all 256 ANSI symbols (some of which are unprintable, like #13, #7, #10), and it won't even be a "pack", just first 4 bytes will hold one number, second 4 bytes will hold second number, third 4 bytes will hold third number.

If you want to pack TWO 4-byte numbers into a READABLE (printable) string of length 12, you need to be able to stuff 4 bytes into 6 "digits" of a string, thankfully 12 is divisible by 2, and you don't have to play with uneven pack length. So, solving 256^4 <= X^6, we receive  X as 41, meaning yes, if you use a Base64 alphabet (as in comments to previous andwer) you are capable of having such a string.